# Python: SUDS performance

Tags: python, xml, soap, xml-parsing, suds

I'm consuming web service with SUDS and have undesired delay (around 10 secs) after I recieved XML.

```
client = Client(URL)  # WSDL is ~800kB, but initialization is less then 1s
client.service.GetRequestResult(request_id)  # and here I have my probjemes
```

`GetRequestResult` returning XML around 700kb, ~285nodes * 70nodes. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/chuwy/45fd15e79b52f1c3e01c) small chunk.

SUDS processing this XML more then 8 secs on my 2GB hetzner box, all this time CPU is loaded 95% and python trace tells me that some lines in `suds.sxbase` are executed more than 4 million times and some around 1 million times. I suppose that it isn't normal behaviour.

Everything exacerbated by the fact that I can't even initialize the client with other libraries (tried osa and pysimplesoap).

So, my question is it just SUDS behaviour or it's normal speed for 2GB VDS? How can I speed it up? May it be a bug on the service side (for example, type declaration which lead to recursion) which I can discuss with tech support?

P.S. May be SO isn't the right place for such questions, but are there someone encountered active SUDS mailing lists or issue tracker?

Comment: It sounds normal from my experience; I just used PyCallGraph to explore a function that uses SUDS for some things and got something that would not print out on less than 8 pages just representing the internal calls of the module.